# pass data to request method of HttpSocket in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm using the [HttpSocket request](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1520/request) method of CakePHP to perform some requests to some api. I want to send some parameters with my request. Does anybody know how I can send some parameters using that method? For example, let's say I'm sending a request to this url:

```
http://www.mydomain.com
```

but I wanna send parameter to this request for example:

```
username: smith123
password: qwerty
```

If I were to do this with Ajax, I would do something like:

```
$.post('http://www.mydomain.com', {username: "smith123", password: "qwerty"}, 'json');
```

How do I send those parameters (also the type of data expected as specified in the ajax example above) to `http://www.mydomain.com` using the request method of the HttpSocket class of CakePHP

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to use the get or post method, not request, which is the base method.
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1518/get

You can pass parameters in the second argument of the get method as either a string or an array:

```
App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket');
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$results = $HttpSocket->get('http://www.google.com/search', 'q=cakephp');
debug($HttpSocket->response);
```